# Перебор массива с определенным шагом с определенного члена массива

Tags: c#, массивы, перебор

Я уже задавал этот вопрос, но мне не помогли, для реализации кодирования Хэмминга на языке c# необходимо реализовать перебор массива: начиная с n-члена пройти n-членов, сделать пропуск в n-членов и снова пройти n-членов). Для примера, если n = 2, а длина массива равна 10, то нам нужны члены с номерами 1, 2, 5, 6, 9 (если учитывать, что массив начинается с нуля).

Comment: И в чем проблема?

Answer (score 2):

```
var m = 10;
var n = 2;
var indexes = Enumerable.Range(n - 1, m - n + 1).Where(x => (x - n + 1) / n % 2 == 0);
Console.WriteLine(string.Join(" ", indexes));
```

Вывод:

```
1 2 5 6 9
```

или чуть покороче:

```
var indexes = Enumerable.Range(0, m).Where(x => (x + 1) / n % 2 != 0);
```

Comment: Можно как-то адаптировать этот алгоритм, чтобы члены с нужными нами индексами складывались (сложение) в определённую переменную?

Comment: Конечно, `var sum = indexes.Sum(i => array[i]);`

Comment: Что такое array? Не видел, чтобы где то было объявлено

Comment: Это ваш массив, элементы которого вы хотите сложить

Comment: Извиняюсь за глупость, но у меня не работает сложение
`
for (int i = 1; i < Math.Ceiling(Math.Log(inMessage.Length, 2)); i++)
            {
                int n = i;
                var index = codedMessage.Where(x => (x - n + 1) / n % 2 == 0);
                codedMessage[(int)Math.Pow(2, i) - 1] = (byte)index.Sum(j => codedMessage[j]);
            }
`

Comment: Потому что это какой-то другой код. Получение списка индексов должно быть дословно как у меня.

Answer (score 1):

Такой, вот, у меня алгоритм получился:

```
for(int i = 0, countToUse; i < n.length; i += interval) {
    if(n.length - 1 < i + interval) {
        countToUse = n.length - i;
    } else {
        countToUse = interval;
    }
    //countToUse - это то, сколько вы можете использовать от i.
    //например, i = 2, а countToUse = 3. 
    //значит вы можете использовать id массива, равные {2, 3, 4}
    Console.WriteLine($"{i} {countToUse}");
}
```

При n, содержащем 10 элементов, получите следующий вывод:

> 0 4
>   4 4
>   8 2